# Java how to: Generic array creation from class with generic?

Tags: java, generics

I have a class `FirstClass<O>` and a class `SecondClass<O>`, and I want to make an O[] in `SecondClass<O>` inside a routine which is called from `FirstClass<O>`, where O is a generic class parameter. I fail to find how to do this.

I need an O[] specifically (and not `ArrayList<O>` or similar) because I need to get elements from it very often inside the body of a loop, and it matters for the execution time of my algorithm.

So I would want something along these lines.

```
public class FirstClass<O> {
    void someRoutine(n and other params) {
        //Do some stuff
        SecondClass<O> = new SecondClass(n, possibly_other_params);
        //Do some stuff
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SecondClass<O> {
    O[] myArray;
    SecondClass<O>(int n, possibly_other_params) {
        //Here the constructor that creates an O[n]
    }
}
```

Some methods I found on the web, but do not work for my case:

- Use `O[] array = (O[]) new Object[n];` but that doesn't compile.
- Use `Object[] array = new Object[n];` and do an (O) cast every time I request something from the array, but this is way too slow
- Use `Array.newInstance(Class<O> type, int n);`, with `O o;` and `type=o.class` but it complains that `type` is now of type `Class<CAP#1>` instead of type `Class<O>`, whatever CAP#1 means...

How should I do this properly in Java, with optimal execution speed in mind?

Comment: Have you actually profiled this?  Is the casting actually what is causing your performance concerns?  Given that generics in Java are erased at runtime, I don't see an easy work-around here to get it working as you're expecting.  I think you'll be better off trying to re-visit your expected API, then trying to get Java's generics to work they way you *want*.

Comment: Just use `ArrayList`, sheesh.

Comment: The problem with ArrayList is that I constantly need to change one element in the array, and this basically all that this inner loop does and hence is the most expensive part of the algorithm. Repeatedly doing `a[i]=a[j]` to obtain some permutation is quite a bit cheaper than doing `list.set(i,list.get(j))` all the time. Putting a fixed array type makes it indeed faster, but then I need to make copy-paste the code for each of the 25 possible types O can be, and that's not really good style. :/ Well, if it's not possible then it's not possible of course. Thanks for the input anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's handling of generics is in pretty rough shape but you can accomplish something close to what you want if you are prepared to make small adjustments. Please see:

```
public class FirstClass<O> {
    Class<O> type;

    public static <O> FirstClass<O> create(Class<O> type) {
        return new FirstClass<O>(type);
    }

    public FirstClass(Class<O> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void routine(int size /*, other params */ ) {
        SecondClass<O> instance = new SecondClass<O>(type, size);
    }
}

public class SecondClass<O> {
    public O[] array;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public SecondClass(Class<O> type,int size) {
        array = (O[])Array.newInstance(type,size);
    }
}
```

And a use case:

```
FirstClass<Integer> instance = FirstClass.create(Integer.class);
instance.routine(110);
```

This is just a rough example although I am sure you could accomplish something similar without having to use this approach.

Comment: Use a factory method to infer the type, it can simplify the code! `static <T> FirstClass<T> create(final Class<T> type) { ... }` and `instance = FirstClass.create(Integer.class);`

Comment: Not to mention you're wrong about not being able to use primitives... see [`Integer.TYPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE), or, equivalently, `int.class`.

Comment: @oldrinb I think he meant the use of generics precluded primitives, not the `Array.newInstance` call itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Use O[] array = (O[]) new Object[n]; but this requires an (O) cast
>   every time I request something from the array, so this is way too slow

What? The whole point of type `O[]` is that you *don't* need an `(O)` cast when getting things out of it

Comment: Sorry, apparently I missed there. It is corrected now: using `O[] array = (O[]) new Object[n];` is impossible as these types are inconvertible, the thing that requires (O) casting every time is `Object[] array = new Object[n];`.

Comment: @user1111929: "is impossible as these types are inconvertible" Not really. `O` is type-erased to `Object`. As long as the array does not escape the scope of `O`, it won't cause any problems.

Comment: You are correct, my apologies. It's not the same speed as a native O[], but it works and it's much cleaner than the `(O[])Array.newInstance(type,size)` solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Repeating my comment from above to hopefully mark this question as answered:

Have you actually profiled this? Is the casting actually what is causing your performance concerns? Given that generics in Java are erased at runtime, I don't see an easy work-around here to get it working as you're expecting. I think you'll be better off trying to re-visit your expected API, then trying to get Java's generics to work they way you want.

Comment: I created for you a simplified version of my algorithm, with approprioate time measuring: http://pastebin.com/QeCW0W1R As you can verify on your computer, the casting causes a 35%-50% delay. This is not something minor. In my more involved final version it is only 15-20% delay, but still, it's not something to just forget about if there are any alternatives.

Comment: Actually, your benchmark is noticeably flawed, and doesn't leave the time for the JIT to warm up or anything.  I wouldn't trust its results to be accurate.  Try using a tool like [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) that knows how to do proper benchmarking in Java.

Comment: Depends on how you use it. I ran the benchmark 5 times in this order and 5 times with the order of the tests reversed, the results were always the same. Still noticeably flawed if used in that way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.set%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) for `ArrayList.set`:

```
public E set(int index, E element) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    E oldValue = elementData(index);
    elementData[index] = element;
    return oldValue;
}
```

Granted, it does an additional lookup to get the old element, which you don't care about, but this is random access we're talking about (read: O(1) time). Just use `ArrayList` unless you have hard numbers to show it's slowing you down.

Comment: I created for you a simplified version of my algorithm, with approprioate time measuring: http://pastebin.com/NUj90ZPv As you can verify on your computer, there is always a factor 4 difference between using `None[]` and `ArrayList<None>` for this algorithm.

Comment: @user1111929 Well, I can't argue with that. Try Jordan White's solution - that should work assuming creation of the array itself is rare.

Comment: I don't see a direct way to test it, but out of curiosity, why would the creation of the array in his solution be more expensive than creating an ArrayList<O>? Doesn't that create a new O[] internally in pretty much the same way?

Comment: `Array.newInstance` uses reflection/native magic to create the dynamically typed array, making it slightly slower. The difference is probably negligible even for your requirements though.

Comment: Actually, your benchmark is noticeably flawed, and doesn't leave the time for the JIT to warm up or anything.  I wouldn't trust its results to be accurate.  Try using a tool like [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) that knows how to do proper benchmarking in Java.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I thought of that aspect and modified his microbenchmark to run the two test loops prior to running them again with timing. Is that still a naive approach as opposed to using Caliper for example?

Comment: That's...better, but benchmarking in Java is hard enough that I don't trust any benchmarks I could write myself unaided.

Comment: Depends on how you use it. I ran the benchmark 5 times in this order and 5 times with the order of the tests reversed, the results were always the same.